# If $C = \mathbb P^1$ how can I show that : deg $K_C = -2\,$ considering the differential form $ω = dz$ on $\mathbb C$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth algebraic curve and $K_C$ its canonical divisor.

If $C = \mathbb P^1$ how can I show that : deg $K_C = -2\,$  considering the differential form $ω = dz$ on
$\mathbb C$ ?
 Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I will just post this answer as a comment since you wanted to work with differential forms, but this follows immediately from your other question that you asked like an hour ago/my answer there since the genus of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $0$.

Comment: @TMO The aim of this exercise is to show that deg $K_C = 2g(C) - 2$, I can't use it.

Comment: What are your definitions of the canonical divisor, degree etc. There are various levels of sophistication that one can do here (as you could see by my answer on your other question) and it is just easier to answer if we have a better idea what your defintions are and what you are allowed to assume. I guess you want to compute that $K_C$ is linearly equivalent to  $-2H$ for some hyperplane $H$ then by really considering poles etc.? This would yield $\text{deg}(K_C) = -2$.

Answer (score 2):

$dz$ is a meromorphic form on $\mathbb{P}^1$ and thus the degree of the canonical bundle is sum of the zeroes of $dz$ minus the its poles. $dz$ has no zeroes or poles on the affine piece and so, you only have to find its zeroes or poles at infinity. At infinity, the local parameter is $u=1/z$ and thus $dz=d(\frac{1}{u})=-\frac{1}{u^2}du$, so has a pole of order 2.